# Animation End Callback for CALayer?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I'm wondering where the callbacks are (or if there are anything) for animations in a CALayer. Specifically, for implied animations like altering the frame, position, etc. In a UIView, you could do something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"SlideOut" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animateOut:finished:context:)];
CGRect frame = self.frame;
frame.origin.y = 480;
self.frame = frame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Specifically, the `setAnimationDidStopSelector` is what I want for an animation in a CALayer. Is there anything like that?

TIA.

Comment: For anyone googling here, I have put in a modern answer to this incredibly old question!  :O Search down to "2017..."

Answer (score 70, accepted):

I answered my own question. You have to add an animation using `CABasicAnimation` like so:

```
CABasicAnimation* anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"frame"];
anim.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:layer.frame];
anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:frame];
anim.delegate = self;
[layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"frame"];
```

And implement the delegate method `animationDidStop:finished:` and you should be good to go. Thank goodness this functionality exists! :D

Comment: This answer is useful for the information about delegate, but it has one big flaw - you can't animate "frame" as it is a derived property. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2008/qa1620.html

Comment: You cannot edit 'frame' but it is just as easy to get the center of the frame and animate the position, for example --> let theAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "position"); and then to get the frame center point -->             theAnimation.fromValue = NSValue(cgPoint: CGPoint(x: rightImage.frame.origin.x + rightImage.frame.width / 2.0, y: rightImage.frame.origin.y + rightImage.frame.height / 2.0))

Comment: please note that this 10 year old answer is really not the way to go.  (that's true of many old answers on SO !)

Comment: @Fattie - and why would that be? Are there any deprecation notices I missed?

Answer (score 135):

You could use a CATransaction, it has a completion block handler.

```
[CATransaction begin];
CABasicAnimation *pathAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"strokeEnd"];
[pathAnimation setDuration:1];
[pathAnimation setFromValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f]];    
[pathAnimation setToValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f]];
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{_lastPoint = _currentPoint; _currentPoint = CGPointMake(_lastPoint.x + _wormStepHorizontalValue, _wormStepVerticalValue);}];
[_pathLayer addAnimation:pathAnimation forKey:@"strokeEnd"];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Note that it is important to set the completion block BEFORE you add the animation to the layer.

Comment: This is not useful always because you get called also when you remove the animation even if did not finish.

Answer (score 70):

#### For 2018 ...

Couldn't be easier.

Don't forget the `[weak self]` or you'll crash.

```
func animeExample() {
    
    CATransaction.begin()
    
    let a = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "fillColor")
    a.fromValue, duration = ... etc etc
    
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock{ [weak self] in
        self?.animeExample()
        self?.ringBell()
        print("again...")
    }
    
    someLayer.add(a, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

#### Critical tip:

You *MUST* have `setCompletionBlock` *BEFORE* the `someLayer.add`.

The order is critical! It's an iOS quirk.

In the example, it just calls itself again.

Of course, you can call any function.

---

***Notes for any anyone new to iOS animations:***

1. The "key" (as in `forKey`) is **irrelevant and rarely used**. Set it to nil. If you want to set it, set it to "any string".
2. The "keyPath" is in fact **the actual "thing you are animating"**. It is literally a **property of the layer** such as "opacity", "backgroundColor" etc, but ***written as a string***.  (You can't just type in "anything you want" there, it has to be the name of an actual property of the layer, and, it has to be animatable.)

To repeat: the "key" (rarely used - just set it to nil) and the "keyPath" are totally unrelated to each other.

You often see example code where these two are **confused** (thanks to the silly naming), which causes all sorts of problems.

---

Note that alternately you can use the delegate, but it's far easier to just use the completion block, since (A) it's self-contained and can be used anywhere and (B) you usually have more than one anime, in which case using the delegate is a bore.

Comment: Great answer Fattie – thank you! Would you mind to explain the `[weak self]` part in detail? For me it also works without it.

Comment: this is really useful, thumb up!

Answer (score 56):

Here is an answer in Swift 3.0 based on bennythemink's solution:

```
    // Begin the transaction
    CATransaction.begin()
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
    animation.duration = duration //duration is the number of seconds
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 1
    animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
    circleLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0

    // Callback function
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock { 
        print("end animation")
    }

    // Do the actual animation and commit the transaction
    circleLayer.add(animation, forKey: "animateCircle")
    CATransaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 50):

Wasted 4 hours with this garbage, just to do a fade in fade out. 
Note the comment in the code.

```
   [CATransaction begin];
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
    animation.duration = 0.3;
    animation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
    animation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
  ///  [box addAnimation:animation forKey:@"j"]; Animation will not work if added here. Need to add this only after the completion block.

    [CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{

        CABasicAnimation *animation2 = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
        animation2.duration = 0.3;
        animation2.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime()+1;
        animation2.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f];
        animation2.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];
        animation2.removedOnCompletion = NO;
        animation2.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
        [box addAnimation:animation2 forKey:@"k"];

    }];

    [box addAnimation:animation forKey:@"j"];

    [CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: I guess, that in your cause you could have used the autoreverse property, because what you are doing is basically reversing the first animation.

Comment: This answer made me laugh! I have totally been there trying to get a seemingly small thing to work for several hours...✊

Comment: They say you should not use `animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;` instead set the value of your layer before initiating animation. This way you are messing up presentation and model layer..

Answer (score 13):

In **Swift 4+** i have just added `delegate` as

```
class CircleView: UIView,CAAnimationDelegate {
...

let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
animation.delegate = self//Set delegate
```

**Animation completion callback -**

```
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
     print("Animation END")
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

Just a note for those who find this page on Google:  You really can get the job done by setting the "delegate" property of your animation object to the object that will receive the notification and implementing the "animationDidStop" method in that object's .m file.  I just tried it, and it works.  I don't know why Joe Blow said that's not the correct way.

Comment: Tried everything from removeAllAnimations to specific CAAnimations with the setCompletionBlock and CATransation.begin and commit like user3077725's answer. Tried UIView.animateWIthDuration. Didn't work for a simple alpha and position.x animation. The delegate method was the only thing that worked properly

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 5.0**

```
func blinkShadow(completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
    CATransaction.begin()
    let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "shadowRadius")
    animation.fromValue = layer.shadowRadius
    animation.toValue = 0.0
    animation.duration = 0.1
    animation.autoreverses = true
    CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion)
    layer.add(animation, forKey: nil)
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: This worked for me very well, but I had to use:

CATransaction.setCompletionBlock(completion) in Swift 5 and also make sure that:

    animation.fillMode = .forwards
    animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

was set to make sure that any animations that chained together did not break for chained items. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name of a given animation when setting up the CAAnimation object.  In animationDiStop:finished, just compare the name of theAnimation object provided to perform you specific functionality based on the animation.

Comment: There is no name property?

Answer (score 0):

For 2020 ...

ValueAnimator, update ur custom properties.

https://github.com/Only-IceSoul/ios-jjvalueanimator

```
 class OnAnimationListener : AnimatorListener {

        weak var s : ViewController?

        init(_ ins: ViewController) {
            s = ins
        }
        func onAnimationStart(_ animation: Animator) {}
        func onAnimationEnd(_ animation: Animator) {

           print("end")
           s?.label.text = "end"

        }
        func onAnimationCancel(_ animation: Animator) {}
        func onAnimationRepeat(_ animation: Animator) {}

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension on CAAnimation which gives you a began & a finished closure, as I was getting fed up of implementing the delegate, especially for multiple animations where you'd have to do horrible stuff like using the animation's key to see which animation was calling the delegate - makes this sort of thing really easy.

It's on GitHub - [Animation Actions](https://github.com/franklynw/AnimationActions)

Hopefully useful to someone!