# Setting CALayer.AnchorPoint animated

Tags: animation, xamarin.ios, calayer

I'm trying to set the AnchorPoint with an animation but it doesnt work.
I tried animating with UIView:

```
UIView.BeginAnimations("Test");
UIView.SetDuAnimationDuration(1f);
Layer.AnchorPoint = new Point(0.5,0.5);
UIView.CommitAnimations();
```

But this doesnt work. Does anyone has an idea to animate setting the AnchorPoint?

Thanks in advance
   Alex

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,
I've already solved my question.

The answer was the combination of this two links:

[Implementing a CAKeyFrameAnimation callback in MonoTouch at the end of an animation set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2219965/implementing-a-cakeyframeanimation-callback-in-monotouch-at-the-end-of-an-animat)

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/AnimProps.html