# Creating a progress indicator with a rounded rectangle

Tags: swift, formula, cashapelayer

I am attempting to create a rounded-rectangle progress indicator in my app. I have previously implemented a circular indicator, but not like this shape. I would like it to look something like this (start point is at the top):

[image]

But I get this with `0` as the `.strokeStart` property of the layer:

[image]

My current code place in `viewDidLoad()`:

```
let queueShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
let queuePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: addToQueue.frame, cornerRadius: addToQueue.layer.cornerRadius)
queueShapeLayer.path = queuePath.cgPath
queueShapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
queueShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
queueShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
queueShapeLayer.strokeStart = 0
queueShapeLayer.strokeEnd = 0.5
view.layer.addSublayer(queueShapeLayer)
```

*`addToQueue` is the button which says 'Upvote'.*

Unlike creating a circular progress indicator, I cannot set the start and end angle in the initialisation of a Bezier path.

How do I make the progress start from the top middle as seen in the first image?

**Edit - added a picture without corner radius on:**

[image]

It seems that the corner radius is creating the issue.

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Comment: Instead of doing all the setup in `viewDidLoad`, I'd recommend creating  custom `UIView` subclass. Also, it would be helpful if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: @Cristik What would help if I made a custom `UIView` subclass, I don't see any benefits? Also, I believe that my question is Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable. Can you expand on why it isn't?

Comment: For starters the code from the question doesn't compile. We should be able to just take the code and throw it into a playground. That would make it easier for people to help you.

Comment: @Cristik Ok I just added the first line from elsewhere in the program. Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for animation? Your two screenshots (along with what else in your question) suggests so. I'm certainly no expert at CoreAnimation (which is what CALayers are about) but `viewDidLoad` seems like the complete wrong place for anything. Maybe start with a more basic example? Say a *rectangular* shape (no `cornerRadius`) and get *it* working? I'd think if you use `draw(rect:)` along with a simple rectangle it would be a simple thing to get a curved border working.

Comment: @dfd It automatically animates when you change the `strokeEnd`. All I am looking for is to be able to find the correct `strokeStart` value so the loading indicator works as expected (starts in the right place).

Comment: My bad. Terribly misread the question. (Still keeping my upvote though.) I'm of no help, except for what I was asking - does it work with `cornerRadius == 0`? Or is all this `cornerRadius` just noise to the *actual* issue?

Comment: @dfd You are right, when I set the radius to `0`, the strange offset went away. So now I need to calculate the correct point  (check updated question).

Comment: Well, actually I'm wrong! If the offset goes away without a cornerRadius, then that **is** the issue. (Still of no more help than that though.) Maybe you'll figure it out on your own - please, if so, post the answer.

Comment: @dfd I have managed to figure out the answer after some time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution so the loading indicator works for round corners:

[image]

```
let queueShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    // Queue timer
    let radius = addToQueue.layer.cornerRadius
    let diameter = radius * 2
    let totalLength = (addToQueue.frame.width - diameter) * 2 + (CGFloat.pi * diameter)

    let queuePath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: addToQueue.frame, cornerRadius: radius)
    queueShapeLayer.path = queuePath.cgPath
    queueShapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
    queueShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    queueShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    queueShapeLayer.strokeStart = 0.25 - CGFloat.pi * diameter / 3 / totalLength // Change the '0.25' to 0.5, 0.75 etc. wherever you want the bar to start
    queueShapeLayer.strokeEnd = queueShapeLayer.strokeStart + 0.5 // Change this to the value you want it to go to (in this case 0.5 or 50% loaded)
    view.layer.addSublayer(queueShapeLayer)
}
```

After I had did this though, I was having problems that I couldn't animate the whole way round. To get around this, I created a second animation (setting `strokeStart` to `0`) and then I placed [completion blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296967/animation-end-callback-for-calayer) so I could trigger the animations at the correct time.

*Tip:*

Add `animation.fillMode = CAMediaTimingFillMode.forwards` & `animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false` when using a `CABasicAnimation` for the animation to wait until you remove it.

I hope this formula helps anyone in the future!

If you need help, you can always message me and I am willing to help. :)

Comment: This is wrong. The right answer is simple. If you want the path to start at the top center, then `UIBezierPath(roundedRect:` is too crude; you must create a path, yourself, that starts at the top center. Line, arc, line, arc, line.

Comment: @matt What do you suggest I therefore should use?

Comment: Gosh I thought I just told you in my previous comment: "you must create a path, yourself, that starts at the top center".

Comment: @matt I am just looking at paths now, I have never used them before. Thanks :)