# How to add animations to an already running animation based on the progress of the latter?

Tags: ios, animation, uiviewanimation, uiviewpropertyanimator

### OBJECTIVE

Building a complex animation where some actions are triggered based on its progress.

### QUESTION

Is it possible to check the progress of a `UIViewPropertyAnimator` and add animations when it reaches a given fraction complete that:

- does not use `UIView.animateKeyframes`
- does not require a user
  intervention

In other words, when the animator reaches a given fractionComplete, some animations are added to it.

### ISSUES

The full animation comprises multiple animations of different objects (stored in an array).  I need to **both add animations at given times (based of % of completion) and add actions when some animations are completed**.

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: Just a NOTE - this may be useful Chris https://stackoverflow.com/a/47536770/294884

Comment: Thanks @Fattie . I use quite regularly CATransaction and it is indeed very useful. I am actually using it to disable some animations within the fullAnimation. Sadly, it does not work for my purpose...

Comment: Gotchya.  BTW is it possible this article could help: https://medium.com/@thibault.wittemberg/elegantly-chaining-uiviewpropertyanimators-88409c64f845

Comment: Thanks :) Interesting indeed. At first glance more for chaining anims than to observe, but I will dig into it :)

Comment: Right, there are no "triggers" in animes in iOS (if you also work with game engines?) ..... so I mean, I may misunderstand you but I'd just start a timer (get the anime length and multiply by the fraction to get the seconds).  Again I may misunderstand the need here!  cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some property, you can control delayFactor to add animation to replace previous target.

```
       let animView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 200))
    animView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green

 animator =    UIViewPropertyAnimator.init(duration: 5.0, curve: UIView.AnimationCurve.easeInOut)

    view.addSubview(animView)
    animator.addCompletion { (position : UIViewAnimatingPosition) in
        if position == UIViewAnimatingPosition.end{
            animView.center  = CGPoint.init(x: 100, y: 300)
        }
    }
    animator.addAnimations({
        animView.center  = CGPoint.init(x: 600, y: 300)
    })
    animator.addAnimations({

        animView.center = CGPoint.init(x: 200, y: 200)
    }, delayFactor: 0.1)
    animator.addAnimations({

        animView.center = CGPoint.init(x: 300, y: 600)
    }, delayFactor: 0.5)
    animator.addAnimations({

        animView.center = CGPoint.init(x: 400, y: 400)
    }, delayFactor: 0.9)

        animator.startAnimation()
```

Comment: Thanks @E.Coms ! I literally bumped on it a few minutes ago and I was about to post it. That's quite the thing I was looking for. I have still some issues to work around though, but that's coding, right?

Answer (score 0):

UIView Animations are designed for light weight animations.

If you want to build complex animations I think is better to use [CAAnimation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimation).

You can use [CAAnimationGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/caanimationgroup) and [keyTimes](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cakeyframeanimation/1412522-keytimes) to synchronise and group them.

One reference that might help is "[How to Create a Complex Loading Animation in Swift](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1746-how-to-create-a-complex-loading-animation-in-swift)" tutorial from raywenderlich.com

Comment: Thanks Alex. I have tried CAAnimation but I have too many properties to animate. PropertyAnimators allow me 1/ to be able to scrub in easily, 2/ to animate various properties at the same place.